# Systems of linear modular equations with unknowns in the moduli

Tags: algorithms, diophantine-equations, computer-algebra, congruences

I am interested in systems of linear modular equations, where the unknowns also appear in the moduli. The general form would be:

$A \vec{x}= \vec{b} \;\textrm{mod} \; (C \vec{x}+\vec{d})$

where A and C are constant integer matrices, $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ are constant vectors in $\mathbb{Z}^d$ and $\vec{x}$ is the unknown vector in $\mathbb{Z}^d$.

In order for the mod to make sense, let us throw in some inequalities as well:

$C \vec{x}+\vec{d} > \vec{1}$ where $\vec{1}$ is the all one vector.

**Question:** Are these equations decidable? If yes, is there a bound known on the size of one solution? If no, is there a reduction from Matiyasevich's theorem?

Note: [Cross-posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1425500/systems-of-linear-modular-equations-with-unknowns-in-the-moduli) from M.SE where this received no answer.

Comment: These equations are solvable, of course it depends on what kind they have and what is the dependence of the number of unknowns to number of equations.  But what about the algorithms?  The solution of such systems is a standard procedure.

Comment: @individ I am curious about this standard procedure, would you mind giving a few details/keywords or providing a reference?

Comment: Good old Gauss-Jordan elimination, for solving systems of linear equations.  Then we must separate the kind of solutions we need.

Comment: @individ Gaussian elimination in which field? Or if you mean Smith normal form over the integers, don't you miss solutions?

Comment: The system is equivalent to a system of quadratic equations $A\vec{x} = \vec{b} + \mathrm{diag}(\vec{y})(C\vec{x}+\vec{d})$ in variables $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$.